# How can I force file association update without admin rights on win7?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++

On windows 7 I previously used `Foo\notepad++.exe` to open `.txt` files, now that has been deleted and I want to use `Bar\notepad++.exe`. When I use the Windows OpenWith menu option on a `.txt` file and Browse to `Bar\notepad++.exe` and try and add it, notepad++ is not added to the Other Programs list in the window and so I cannot open it.

WHen I encountered this problem under XP I found it was caused by the name of the executable being the same across two locations, which seems to confuse windows. In that instance I solved the problem with the excellent OpenWithAdd utility, however this is not an option on windows 7 as I do not have admin rights to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need admin rights to make that change. It might be possible to make that change without admin rights if UAC was turned off (I'm not even sure it that would work), but you would need admin rights to turn UAC off anyway.

This is a one time thing to run with admin rights and make the change. You won't need permanent or long-term admin rights after the change is made.

If in your case, you can't get admin rights for yourself on your machine, it seems to be a simple request you could make for an admin to make the change for you.